# Account Hierarchy ? Parent account has children in which child could become a parent

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

I have 2 tables.  One table contains all parent accounts, top level of hierarchy.  Second table has all children accounts, that may or may not have a match to a parent account in the parent table.  The goal is to create a query (SQL Server 2008, recursive or non) that finds all child accounts that match to the parent in addition to the fact that the child could itself be a parent to other child accounts.

In simpler terms, once a match has been made on a parent to child, need to check to make sure that the child in the match is not itself a parent to other child accounts.  A mouthful I understand and I hope it makes sense.  I also do not know the depth of which the hierarchy would extend.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Parent_Accounts
(Parent_Account_Key_Lookup     varchar(28)          NOT NULL,
 Account_Number            bigint       NOT NULL,
 Reference_Account_Number_1        bigint       NOT NULL,
 Reference_Account_Number_2        bigint       NOT NULL,
 OpenDate              int          NOT NULL,
 Status                        char(1)              NOT NULL,
 Record_Created            smalldatetime    NOT NULL,
 Active                bit          NOT NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Child_Accounts
(Child_Account_Key_Lookup      varchar(28)          NOT NULL,
 Account_Number            bigint       NOT NULL,
 Reference_Account_Number_1        bigint       NOT NULL,
 Reference_Account_Number_2        bigint       NOT NULL,
 OpenDate              int          NOT NULL,
 Status                        char(1)              NOT NULL,
 Record_Created            smalldatetime    NOT NULL,
 Active                bit          NOT NULL)
GO

    WITH cte_Recursive
AS  (SELECT parent.Account_Number,
        parent.Parent_Account_Key_Lookup,
        parent.Reference_Account_Number_1,
        parent.Reference_Account_Number_2,
        parent.OpenDate,
        parent.[Status],
        parent.Record_Created,
        parent.Active,
        1 AS Hierarchy_Level
     FROM dbo.Parent_Accounts parent
     WHERE parent.Account_Number = 4498481055218674
     UNION ALL
     SELECT child.Account_Number,
        child.Child_Account_Key_Lookup,
        child.Reference_Account_Number_1,
        child.Reference_Account_Number_2,
        child.OpenDate,
        child.[Status],
        child.Record_Created,
        child.Active,
        cte.Hierarchy_Level + 1
     FROM cte_Recursive cte
     INNER JOIN dbo.Child_Accounts child
         ON cte.Parent_Account_Key_Lookup = child.Child_Account_Key_Lookup)

    --SELECT * FROM cte_Recursive
            SELECT TOP 2 * FROM cte_Recursive

INSERT INTO dbo.Parent_Accounts
 (Parent_Account_Key_Lookup, 
  Account_Number, 
  Reference_Account_Number_1, 
  Reference_Account_Number_2, 
  OpenDate, 
  [Status], 
  Record_Created, 
  Active)
 VALUES ('222248105521867419970702', 2222481055218674, 2222481060975466, 0, 19970702, 'U', '2010-11-18 12:46:00', 0)

 INSERT INTO dbo.Child_Accounts
 (Child_Account_Key_Lookup, 
  Account_Number, 
  Reference_Account_Number_1, 
  Reference_Account_Number_2, 
  OpenDate, 
  [Status], 
  Record_Created, 
  Active)
 VALUES ('222248105521867419970702', 2222481060975466, 2222481055218674, 2222481055218674, 19970702, 'L', '2010-11-19 08:33:00', 0),
    ('222248106097546619970702', 2222481060982900, 2222481060989137, 2222481060975466, 19970702, 'U', '2010-11-19 16:54:00', 0),
    ('222248106098290019970702', 2222481060989137, 0,                2222481060982900, 19970702, ' ', '2010-11-21 01:52:00', 1)
```

Comment: Once you've found a match between child and parent can't you just check to see if the corresponding child ID is present as a parent in the parent table? If children can be parents, any that are should also be present in the parent table.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the results to look like?

Comment: I have added the data to populate the tables

Comment: That is the catch.  Once I have found a match I would need to insert that child into the parents and repeat the cycle.

Comment: I don't get it, how do you know a child is a parent if it's not already in the parent table?

Comment: Because once I have found a match, I would then need to insert that child that matched into the parent table and then match back to the children to determine if the child was a parent.  Maybe I am looking at this all wrong.

Comment: Since the fields looks quite similar between tables, is there a reason that you haven't used a single table where each row has a `ParentId`?  A typical design is that roots in the hierarchy have a `NULL` value for `ParentId`, all other nodes have the parent's Id.  Or do have a specific need for orphans, i.e. explicit children without parents?

Comment: Yes would need to know the orphaned children.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be an inability to specify how to determine that a child has children combined with a lack of identity for children.  If the `ON` clause in the CTE could prevent a child joining to itself it would break the infinite recursion chain.

Sample output and answers to the comments should make it clear whether you simply need another condition in the `ON` clause or a `UNION` to handle childrens' children.

This at least stops recursing by limiting the hierarchy level and provides a testbed that anyone can execute without cluttering their database:

```
declare @Parent_Accounts as table (
  Parent_Account_Key_Lookup varchar(28) NOT NULL, 
  Account_Number bigint NOT NULL, 
  Reference_Account_Number_1 bigint NOT NULL, 
  Reference_Account_Number_2 bigint NOT NULL, 
  OpenDate int NOT NULL, 
  Status char(1) NOT NULL, 
  Record_Created smalldatetime NOT NULL, 
  Active bit NOT NULL) 

declare @Child_Accounts as table (
  Child_Account_Key_Lookup varchar(28) NOT NULL, 
  Account_Number bigint NOT NULL, 
  Reference_Account_Number_1 bigint NOT NULL, 
  Reference_Account_Number_2 bigint NOT NULL, 
  OpenDate int NOT NULL, 
  Status char(1) NOT NULL, 
  Record_Created smalldatetime NOT NULL, 
  Active bit NOT NULL) 

INSERT INTO @Parent_Accounts 
  (Parent_Account_Key_Lookup, Account_Number, Reference_Account_Number_1, Reference_Account_Number_2, OpenDate, [Status], Record_Created, Active) VALUES
  ('222248105521867419970702', 2222481055218674, 2222481060975466, 0, 19970702, 'U', '2010-11-18 12:46:00', 0) 

 INSERT INTO @Child_Accounts 
  (Child_Account_Key_Lookup, Account_Number, Reference_Account_Number_1, Reference_Account_Number_2, OpenDate, [Status], Record_Created, Active) VALUES
  ('222248105521867419970702', 2222481060975466, 2222481055218674, 2222481055218674, 19970702, 'L', '2010-11-19 08:33:00', 0), 
  ('222248106097546619970702', 2222481060982900, 2222481060989137, 2222481060975466, 19970702, 'U', '2010-11-19 16:54:00', 0), 
  ('222248106098290019970702', 2222481060989137, 0, 2222481060982900, 19970702, ' ', '2010-11-21 01:52:00', 1) 

; WITH cte_Recursive 
AS (SELECT parent.Account_Number, 
 parent.Parent_Account_Key_Lookup, 
 parent.Reference_Account_Number_1, 
 parent.Reference_Account_Number_2, 
 parent.OpenDate, 
 parent.[Status], 
 parent.Record_Created, 
 parent.Active, 
 1 AS Hierarchy_Level 
 FROM @Parent_Accounts parent 
 WHERE parent.Account_Number = 2222481055218674 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT child.Account_Number, 
 child.Child_Account_Key_Lookup, 
 child.Reference_Account_Number_1, 
 child.Reference_Account_Number_2, 
 child.OpenDate, 
 child.[Status], 
 child.Record_Created, 
 child.Active, 
 cte.Hierarchy_Level + 1 
 FROM cte_Recursive cte 
 INNER JOIN @Child_Accounts child 
 ON cte.Parent_Account_Key_Lookup = child.Child_Account_Key_Lookup and cte.Hierarchy_Level < 2) 
 SELECT * FROM cte_Recursive
```